# Error Handling in VB 6.0 DLL

Tags: dll, vb6

I am writing a DLL that I will use to automate Excel. I would like to set up an extensive error handling module. What I can't figure out is how to exit the entire DLL on an error. I can't use the End statement in a DLL. Application.Quit does nothing either.

If I am in a low level sub, and I run an error handler and then Exit Sub, it will just go up another level etc. In .NET there are 'exceptions'. Anything similar in VB 6.0?

Thanks.

Comment: a DLL is neither entered nor exited.  code procedures in them are (though they can go on and on).

Comment: Okay. If I enter a code procedure which calls another, which call another..., and I have an error five levels down, how can I stop all procedures.

Comment: if they are functions, they can return an error code and the caller can see it and just return that value back up the call chain

Comment: The automation APIs of Office products aren't really robust enough to bury within a DLL.  They only exist for top-level automation directly under user control, since they can result in arbitrary dialogs being popped up, interference with other visible instances of open Office documents, etc.

Comment: And what do you mean by a dll that automates excel. Something has to run dlls.

Comment: Functions and subroutines of the DLL get called by VBA.

Comment: There are a lot of reasons that you have to be careful using Office Automation in a DLL.  Not the least of these are the things that can go wrong that Bob has mentioned.  Importantly, a DLL becomes part of the process that instantiates its objects, whereas Automation creates a separate process, i. e. runs another EXE.  The only way to control the Automation object is by sending method calls that it supports.  So, a few things that can help are to make the Excel instance invisible, and to make sure that you call its Quit method when you're done using it.

Answer (score 1):

While what Plutonix says is true, there is something more similar to exception handling that you can use as well.  You can create an vbObjectError of your own and raise that up the call stack via the error handling mechanism.

First, create some error in your mind.  Best practice is to use a number that has vbObjectError (a very large negative number) added to it, so as not to collide with native VB errors.  Then, do something like this:

```
Public Sub MySub()
On Error Goto errHandle
'do  stuff
Exit Sub
errHandle:
Select Case Err.Number - vbObjectError
    Case 1
        'Do This
    Case 2
        'Do That
    Case 1000
        Err.Raise 1000 + vbObjectError, "Fatal Error, Really we Gotta Leave", _
        "My DLL"
End Select
End Sub
```

So, the thing I think you are missing in all this is that if you raise an error in your error handler, it gets re-raised in the calling proc.  If you keep re-raising the "exit error" like this in all your error handlers, the error will bubble up the call stack and eventually make it to your client procedure, the one that instantiates your DLL object.  At that point, you will have exited your DLL object.  In your client object's error handler, you can clean up your object references and so on as needed, and there you are.

Comment: Sounds very interesting. The are a few things here that are new to me. I will research and give it a try. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are most welcome.  Let me know how it turns out.

Comment: Just trying to follow your logic. "Select Case vbObjectError - Err.Number" "Case 1". How would it ever be 1. If a normal runtime error occurred, error #1, would Select Case vbObjectError - Err.Number = 1?

Comment: My bad!  I'm a bit dyslexic and it caught me.  That should be Err.Number - vbObjectError, not the other way around.  You're supposed to add vbObjectError when you raise the error, and subtract it when you evaluate the error.  See if my edit works better for you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to handle errors in low level subs as VB will bubble errors (which are very similar to exceptions) up the call stack as far as it can. Only if there are no errors at the highest level will your program crash.

```
Going down the call stack: Event > UI code > DLL code > Sub code (error occurs) 
Coming up the call stack: Sub error handler > DLL error handler > UI error handler > Crash
```

That said it's bad practice to only put error handlers at the very top level as then you'll have a much harder time debugging problems.

As a DLL can have a limited set of public procedures as it's interface (you didn't make all those low level subs Public did you?) you can put an error handler in each public procedure and then either handle or raise the error as required. There are several common ways this has been handled over the years which don't really need iterating  again, just search for 'how to handle errors' or something similar.

Comment: Thank you. I rewrote a lot of my code, so now there's only one entry point for all subs. That being said, based on your comment, all I need to do is add an error handler at the entry point and I'm good to go. As far as debugging problems, I can have a variable set with the sub name that caused the error.